# Why does this term converge to $1$?

Tags: limits, factorial

$$\frac{n!}{(n-k-i)!n^{k+i}}\rightarrow1$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I wonder why that is? Thanks for an explanation!

Comment: This can be rewritten as $$\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k-i+1)}{n^{i+k}}.$$ The numerator and denominator are both monic polynomials of degree $i+k.$

Comment: How do you define $n!$ when $n$ is not an integer?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $n\rightarrow\infty$? Otherwise this is asking for factorials that aren't nonnegative integers, which is usually expressed in terms of the gamma function.

Comment: And yes, my comment assumes you meant $n\to\infty.$

Comment: @eyeballfrog Ah yes, I edited it!

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at one example: Suppose $i + k = 5$.

Then you have:

$$\frac{n!}{(n-5)!n^5} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{n^5}$$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the expression above will converge to $1$.

Picking other values of $i + k$ will lead you down a similar road; the task remaining for you is to write it up in a general form (which is essentially done in the comments already posted).